# Controlling which targets are built with CMake add_subdirectory()

Tags: cmake

I'm having an issue with add_subdirectory(), namely, that I can't control which targets are actually built with it - seems to just do an equivalent of `make all`. I may be misusing add_subdirectory(), but as I understand it, it can be used to build dependencies. I'm vendoring a few libraries that my project depends on, and in my project's CMakeLists.txt, I've added add_subdirectory() for each vendored project (all have their own CMakeLists.txt).

Because I'm cross-compiling, I don't want to build any binaries used by these libraries. In one case, I also need another target that's not built by the ALL target in one dependency. As far as I can tell, add_subdirectory() does not make this possible. Is there some way to do this that I'm missing? Is there a better CMake command to use instead?

I previously had this working with shell scripting by just invoking cmake/make on each dependency with the targets I'm interested in, but I'm trying to move this into Android Studio which only supports invoke via CMake.

edit: It's gross, but I'm considering using `add_custom_target` to invoke `cmake` and `cmake --build` manually so that I can control the builds precisely, just as before.

Comment: As far as I understand, CMake creates separate `make` targets for each target in the subdirectory. You don't have to do anything extra for this. When you run `make` try doing `make <target_name>` where `<target_name>` is one of the targets you created in the subdirectory.

Comment: `I don't want to build any binaries used by these libraries.` - If subproject supports disabling those binaries through parameters, set those parameters (with `set(... CACHE ...)`) before `add_subdirectory` call. `I also need another target that's not built by the ALL target in one dependency.` - Just `add_dependency` between one of your target built during ALL and that non-ALL target. You may detect crosscompiling via checking *CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING* CMake variable.

Answer (score 0):

The command [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) supports the option `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` which prevents the targets created in the sub-directory from being included in the `ALL` target of the parent directory. To build only the desired vendored targets then, add target level dependencies for your own project targets.

Comment: How to build the desired targets for another external project that is pulled in via add_subdirectory?

Comment: @stackprotector: excluding the sub-directory from the default `ALL` target via `add_subdirectory(SomeLib EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` (where SomeLib is the source directory), and later using `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SomeLibTarget)` will create a dependency which CMake will use to build just that target.